# Hide an image in CSS if the size of a div get smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this where the size of the title part is defined as a third of the parent:

```css
.entry .title {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">
    <img src="image/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
    <h3>2012 - 2015</h3>
    <p><a href="link">link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
</div>
```

The image has a maximum width of 200 px, and I would like to hide it if the title size is smaller than 200 px. How to do it? I know with `@media` I can hide it if the size of the screen is reduced, but how to take into account the width of the div?

Comment: I would have a look at container queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

Answer (score 0):

The .title div is 33% of the window. You want to hide it if it is smaller than 200px. That means you can simply hide it if the screen width is smaller than 600px.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .entry .title {
        display: none;
    }
}
```